# Want to Hide/Unhide parameters based on any input in Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, parameters, jenkins-pipeline

Below is the set of parameters in my Jenkins pipeline. I'd like to hide/unhide parameters based on some other parameter.
[Click here for params screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSE1f.jpg)

For example, based on the environment selected I'd like to hide/unhide some parameters.

Any leads on how to achieve this?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of [Active Choices Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/uno-choice/).

In the same plugin page, you will get the examples. It is explained in detailed way.